# Replicate Production Django Server + Postgres Database to Identical Linode server as a backup

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, apache2

I am trying to make an identical copy of a production server hosted on Linode. This is a Python/Django/Postgres implementation with tenant model. I am quite new to the implementation done by another developer who has since left.

Current site is live with
tenant1.prodlive.info
tenant2.prodlive.info

The steps I have carried out to take a backup within the linode dashboard and then created a new linode instance with that backup. After logging in, I am seeing all files have been copied correctly.

However, I am missing steps on configuring some specifics due to which the server is showing 404 error when I try to access
tenant1.backup.info
tenant2.backup.info.

The DNS is setup correctly to have A records for both.
Server does respond to the main server url [www.backup.info](http://www.backup.info).

The only file that I have changed is the \project_dir\django_project\middleware.py and changed the mention of the domain name and IP address prodlive.info and ip.prod.live.info to backup.info and ip.back.up.info.

I may be missing some configuration items hence need help with some pointers and best practices to maintain an exact copy of the live production. Thanks in advance for all your suggestions and help.

Here's the exact message I get when accessing the subdomain URL.
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://tenant1.backup.info/
Raised by:  appname.views.index

Answer (score 0):

[Django-tenants](https://github.com/django-tenants/django-tenants) uses PostgreSQL schemas to partition the database into multiple namespaces.

Given that you have manually restored a (previously) working Linode backup, the first thing you should do is get console access to the database and manually inspect which tenants are installed:

```
$ ./manage.py dbshell
postgres=# \d
postgres=# select schema_name, domain from myapp_tenant cross join myapp_domain;

   name   |       domain    
----------+---------------------
 public   | www.backup.info
 tenant1  | tenant1.backup.info
 tenant2  | tenant2.backup.info
```

If all is well, you should see your tenants as listed above. When visiting http://tenant1.backup.info/, `django-tenants` will look up the domain name in the `myapp_domain` table, find the corresponding tenant account and set the PostgreSQL `search_path` to `tenant1`.

However, since you are getting a `404` I suspect that the domain names in the database do not correspond with your currently configured domain names. You can fix this with the proper SQL statements, or simply within the Python shell:

```
./manage.py python
>>> from myapp.models import Domain
>>> Domain.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Domain domain="incorrect_domain.prodlive.info" Tenant="tenant1" is_primary="True">, <Domain domain="another_incorrect_domain.prodlive.info" Tenant="tenant2" is_primary="True">]>
>>> d = Domain.objects.get(domain="incorrect_domain.prodlive.info")
>>> d.domain = "tenant1.backup.info"
>>> d.save()
```

In other words, make sure the domain names that appear in your database are correct, either using the database shell or the Python shell.

Comment: Thanks hedgie, trying out the suggestions below but running into some other issues. Will report back progress. Appreciate the help.